# Знак ## в языке Си

Tags: c, препроцессор

При просмотре алгоритма BlowFish нашел вот такую строчку:

```
#define S(x,i) (SBoxes[i][x.w.byte##i])
```

Что означает `##`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это соединение строк.

В данном случае значение параметра макроса "приклеивается" к `byte`

Допустим, макрос вызвали с параметрами `var` и `1`, то

```
S(var, 1)
```

будет заменено препроцессором на

```
(SBoxes[1][var.w.byte1])
```

а вызов

```
S(var, str)
```

на

```
(SBoxes[str][var.w.bytestr])
```

и так далее

Answer (score 9):

Это token pasting, слияние токенов на уровне препроцессора.

Например, `S(field,5)` раскроется в `(SBoxes[5][field.w.byte5])`.

Документация:

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx)
- [GNU GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)
- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)